# How can I apply custom styles on a reactstrap input?

Tags: css, reactjs, reactstrap

If someone have experience with reactstrap and can help me with a problem: I have a reactstrap Input component and I want to apply "border: none" in styles.scss. In their documentation I don't see the Input component and what props can take. I don't know if I can apply border: none from its props.
So far I've tried in styles.scss:

```
.form-control {
  border: none;
}
```

or

```
#name.form-control {
  border: none;
}
```

or by applying a `className={styles.inputName}` prop on Input component and trying to apply css properties mentioned above.
None of these worked so far.
Thank you.

Comment: Try `className={"border-0"}`

Comment: @codemonkey Thank you, this worked! But can you explain to me please where do I see these properties which can be supported by this input?

Comment: Too long to explain. Added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frameworks like Reactstrap or React Bootstrap come with a CSS file you import. It's a huge file that has all the properties you need. All you do is apply class names to your React components as in `className={"classname1 classname2 ..."}`.

So for borders, here is the doc: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/utilities/borders/
From that doc you can see, for example, that you can remove just the top border by applying this class name `border-top-0`. And there is a class name for just about every imaginable properly e.g. display, margin, padding, width, height etc.

Comment: @Christian No problem. Also remember that even if you can't find an appropriate class for something (say very specific padding), you can also apply custom CSS like so `<Col style={{padding: '13px'}}>`